# Possible to perform an error analysis in excel?

Tags: excel

does anyone know if it's possible to format a number in excel to show the error. Like 7.4 ± 0.1? and if so, is it possible to perform an error analysis with them?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us where Google is failing you on that second question?  http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1717265&seqNum=3

Answer (score 0):

The usual method is to use two cells, one for the value, the other for the tolerance.

For display purposes:

In C1:

**=A1 & "+-" & B1**